# Unity Grid Layout Group Reverse Arrangement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grid-layout

How can I reverse the arrangement of a grid layout group? It is really easy to do it with vertical&horizontal layout groups cuz they literally have a toggle.

[image: Grid Layout Group]

[image: Horizontal Layout Group]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the arrangement of the items by changing the `Start Corner`.

**Upper Left**
`Left To Right, Top To Bottom`

**Upper Right**
`Right To Left, Top To Bottom`

**Lower Left**
`Left To Right, Bottom To Top`

**Lower Right**
`Right To Left, Bottom To Top`

Comment: If GameObject count is odd it doesn't really do what I want to. Thanks for reply. I've found the solution I don't know if it is the best way to do it but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void changeSort(bool setfirst)
{
    var items = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("items");

    foreach (GameObject b in items)
    {
        if (setfirst)
        {
            b.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetAsFirstSibling();
        }
        else
        {
            b.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetAsLastSibling();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).